# LocalDB not installing

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I installed **SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe** which gave me the option of including **LocalDB** which I checked. Yet, VS2013 (Community Edition) can't find it. I've been searching the web for a missing step in the installation but have found none. I already rebooted the computer after installation. I also tried running the installer again, but it shows me that LocalDB *is* already installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you type that in your command prompt:

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" info V11.0

Comment: @CeOnSql I see some information about it (including "State: Stopped").

Comment: Ok so at least we know it's installed...   please try to execute: SqlLocalDB.exe start V11.0

Comment: For more information just google for SqlLocalDB.exe

Comment: @CeOnSql Perfect, Thank a lot! Now it "Started". And now VS found it! a) You can change your comment into an answer. b) Will it now start every time by itself?

Comment: You're welcome :) Dealed with the same problem a few weeks ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case LocalDB is not started.
To Start LocalDB (V11.0 is the default instance name) execute:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe start V11.0
```

To start automatically at System startup have a look at this:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52697/how-to-auto-start-instance-of-sql-server-2012-localdb-on-startup